# transform list with dynamic tag names

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to transform the following xml fragment

```
   <district>
     <name>SOUTH</name>
     <geoCode>18277</geoCode>    
    </district>    
    <district>
     <name>NORTH</name>
     <geoCode>333</geoCode>    
    </district>
```

into

```
<entity id="district">
   <instance id="1">
     <property name="name">SOUTH</property>
     <property name="geoCode">18277</property>
   </instance>
   <instance id="2">
     <property name="name">NORTH</property>
     <property name="geoCode">333</property>
   </instance>
</entity>
```

In other words, my source xml contains list of entities; the result supposed to have an entity group tag whose @id is equal to list tag name and within this group i need to build the list of instances corresponding to the original list entities.
Is it doable using xsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the identity template and then just act on the specific elements that need an action. Namely, putting the `position` and `local-name` into the new elements you are creating.

So you can take this XML (added root to make it well formed).

```
<root>
  <district>
    <name>SOUTH</name>
    <geoCode>18277</geoCode>    
  </district>    
  <district>
    <name>NORTH</name>
    <geoCode>333</geoCode>    
  </district>
</root>
```

And run it against this XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <entity id="district">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </entity>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="district">
  <instance id="{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </instance>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name | geoCode">
  <property name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </property>
</xsl:template>
```

To produce your output.

If you need that last template to be a little more generic you can change the match to

```
<xsl:template match="district/*">
```

Which would act on all child elements of `district` to convert them to the new `property` element.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Can I compare with part of the local-name? in the actual XML message I have several collections, and tags like 'asset_geoc0de", "location_geocode" etc.

Comment: @user3010912 so you might have additional elements under the `district` element? If that is the case then you should be able to update the match to work on all child elements. I'll update the question with an example if that is what you are looking for.